# ASP.NET: Datagrid CurrentRow

Tags: asp.net, loops

I have a DataGrid, with around 100 differnt entries, I am wanting to loop through each row, and get a field form the database(the field is URL), into a string.Basically I have the code to do a screen scrape using the HTMLAgilityPack, but I want to do this for each row in the database, and update the database based upon the returned screen scrape.

1. Loop through each row
2. Store Each URL into a String
3. Use HtmlAgilityPack to do a screen scrape *done*
4. Update Database field "Price" with a value returned from step 3

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the rows in your datagrid and add the value of a specific column to a list of strings.

```
var hyperlinks = new List<string>();
var indexOfColumn = 2; 
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDataGridView.Rows)
{
  hyperlinks.Add(((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[indexOfColumn]).Value);
}
```

Then use the hyperlinks list and update the database as you require in step 4.
I would say you could update the database inside the foreach statement and not bother adding to the list of hyperlinks, but for 100 rows that could be quite costly and unless you've got batching or something similar so you actually only hit the database every 20 updates or so.